# Definir valor para um cookie

Tags: java, cookies

Pretendo alterar um valor em cookie, estou a usar:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection conn;

    url = new URL("http://google.pt");

    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", "COOKIE=QUALQUERCOISA");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "COOKIE=QUALQUERCOISA");

    for (int i = 1; (conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i)) != null; i++) {
        System.out.println(conn.getHeaderField(i));
    }
}
```

O output é:

```
Tue, 18 Aug 2015 17:11:23 GMT  
-1  
private, max-age=0  
text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1  
CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."  
gws  
1; mode=block  
SAMEORIGIN  
PREF=ID=1111111111111111:FF=0:TM=1439917883:LM=1439917883:V=1:S=_eDy4EFOKwUQbSmv; expires=Thu, 17-Aug-2017 17:11:23 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.pt  
NID=70=bVTWaWrDKKfMTdhKERZr8NUlf6hYUzt4y1Sw3umSgjnWubydTDGnDxryyv75KWQPCQkDkJSNStJbwzL7fQPtgZnVRvmQidhvp_wUqBsA679hNpC-kIlzK3sW2Lo8OWA0; expires=Wed, 17-Feb-2016 17:11:23 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.pt; HttpOnly  
none  
Accept-Encoding  
chunked
```

**Não adiciona o novo valor de cookie.**

Comment: Resolvi o problema com:
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie","JSESSIONID=" + string_com_jsessionid);
        conn.connect();

Answer (score 1):

Pagar pegar os Cookies to response header e carregar no cookieManager tente:

```
static final String COOKIES_HEADER = "Set-Cookie";
HttpURLConnection connection = ... ;
static java.net.CookieManager msCookieManager = new java.net.CookieManager();

Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = connection.getHeaderFields();
List<String> cookiesHeader = headerFields.get(COOKIES_HEADER);

if(cookiesHeader != null)
{
    for (String cookie : cookiesHeader) 
    {
      msCookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null,HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
    }               
}
```

Depois para pegar o cookie do cookieManager e carrega-lo no connection:

```
if(msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().size() > 0)
{
    //While joining the Cookies, use ',' or ';' as needed. Most of the server are using ';'
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",
    TextUtils.join(";",  msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()));    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema com:

```
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie","JSESSIONID=" + string_com_jsessionid);
        conn.connect();
```

...